# Which is the fastest way to compare two float value in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two float value ("a" and "b") in Python 3 and each float value can have from 5 to 15 decimal point. The problem is that when two value are equal for me, python return me a False.

```
Examples:
a=12.091824733909107, b=12.091824733909117
or also
a=12.54678, b=12.5467800000123
```

For me in the above examples "a" and "b" are equal. One solution is to use round(a, 5) and round(b,5) to cut decimal point but use round() million of time increase the time process. Is there another solution that not require to use round()?

Comment: This is because the two values are **NOT** equal.

Comment: what happens when you use; if a-b = 0: return true; elif a-b != 0: return false;

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst make a-b don't solve the problem because for example python will recognize from the difference 0.000000001. Furthermore I think is more fast compare two value than make the difference and compare the result to 0

Comment: @Dawny for python are not equal but for me are equal.

Answer (score 3):

you need to set a tolerance range, such that if the difference between a and b is bellow they are considered equals

```
>>> def is_close(a, b, tol=1e-9):
        return abs(a-b) <= tol

>>> is_close(12.091824733909107, 12.091824733909117)
True
>>> is_close(12.54678, 12.5467800000123)
True
>>>
```

or in python 3.5+

```
>>> import math
>>> math.isclose(12.091824733909107, 12.091824733909117)
True
>>> math.isclose(12.54678, 12.5467800000123)
True
>>>
```

Comment: I made some test in python 3.4 and 3.5 and seems that use "%.xf" % a and "%.xf" % b is the fastest solution (x equal to 7 in my case). It's also more fast than math.isclose (some seconds less).